# Convert a number given as a string input to a 32 bit little endian value

Tags: c++

Input -> string: "208705"

Output-> BYTE array: {0x41, 0x2F, 0x03}

I have converted the string to hex format using stringstream:

```
string decStrToHex(string decimalString) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<< std::hex << stoi(decimalString);
    std::string result ( ss.str() );
    return "0" + result;
}
```

How to proceed?

Comment: How should `{0x41, 0x2F, 0x03}` relate to `"208705"` actually? 32 bit integer number representation? Little or big endian architecture?

Comment: My hand calculator, converts 208705 to 0x032f41.  So the first byte of your array is lsByte of decimal integer which is 3 bytes long?  last byte is msByte of number?  What if input string is longer than max digits of uint64_t (multi-precision)?  Your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to convert from a (decimal format) string to a (constant sized hex format) BYTE array: ...

There's no direct conversion from the string to that byte array you want to have.

It looks like you want to convert a number given as a string input to a 32 bit little endian value.

If I put it in my calculator

[image]

and convert it to hex, it looks like

[image]

So the `0x41` is the LSB and shows up last.

How that byte array you are claiming should actually look like and how the bytes are ordered depends on the machine architecture (see [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

First, you just convert the number (there are other ways but I'll take that as example):

```
 uint32_t number;
 std::istringstream iss("208705");
 iss >> number;
```

Next step is to ensure you have a little endian representation of that number:

```
 union LittleEndian32Bit {
     uint32_t uint;
     uint8_t[4] bytes;
 };
```

Such you can have

```
 LittleEndian32Bit le;

 le.bytes[0] = number & 0xFF;
 le.bytes[1] = (number >> 8) & 0xFF;
 le.bytes[2] = (number >> 16) & 0xFF;
 le.bytes[3] = (number >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

> Output BYTE array: {0x41, 0x2F, 0x03}

```
 std::cout << '{';
 for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(le.bytes); ++i) {
     if(i != 0) {
         std::cout << ", ";
     }
     std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
               << (unsigned int)le.bytes[i];
 }
 std::cout << '}' << std::endl;
```

Well, one more for the fourth byte:

```
{0x41, 0x2f, 0x03, 0x00}
```

See [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c8099fdc8414487)

Comment: When using setfill and setw numbers like 3 get padded, how to actually get it as a BYTE (unsigned char)?

Comment: @SiimVeskilt _"When using setfill and setw numbers like 3 get padded"_ What do you mean actually, I don't get it? Output is exactly as I've been showing, there's nothing _"padded"_. If you want the MSB omitted, just loop `for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(le.bytes) - 1; ++i) {`

Comment: I wish the output to be something like BYTE bytes[4] = {0x41, 0x2f, 0x03, 0x00}; which I could feed into a sendPacket function, the 0x03 does not come as 0x03 without the filling.

Comment: @SiimVeskilt You're confusing representation and contents. Sure you need to instruct the text representing stream how to fill up for the required width claimed with `setw()`. The default fill character is `' '`, hence you need to put the `std::setfill('0')` statement.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed array of 3 bytes you can do something like this:

```
unsigned char GetByte(int i, int n)
{
    int Mask = 0xFF;
    Mask <<= n * 8;
    return (i & Mask) >> (n * 8);
}

std::array<unsigned char, 3> decStrToHex(std::string decimalString)
{
    int Val;
    std::stringstream ss(decimalString);
    ss >> Val;

    std::array<unsigned char, 3> Arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        Arr[i] = GetByte(Val, i);

    return Arr;

}
```